# Delphi 10.1 ShellExecute Error incompatible types 'HWND' and 'TWindowsHandle'

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

I have a problem with the following code in Delphi 10.1:

```
ShellExecute(handle,'open',PChar(filename), '','',SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

When I try to run the code it gives me this error:

> Incompatible Types: 'HWND' and 'TWindowHandle'

Comment: Try change `handle` parameter to `0`.

Comment: Ask yourself why you are passing `handle` there. That's the FMX `handle` of a form in your app, I presume. Do you know what `ShellExecute` will do with that argument? Is there any good reason why you would not just pass `0`? What drove you to pass a different value? How well, if at all, do you understand how that argument will be used? If you don't understand it well, why are you even calling the function?

Comment: Don't use `ShellExecute` because it does not report errors in a useful way. Use `ShellExecuteEx` which does. Are you even checking for errors? Do you want to use the `open` verb explicitly, or do you really want to execute the default verb? Is `filename` an executable file? If so then you should create a new process with `CreateProcess` rather than getting the shell to do the work.

Answer (score 5):

In FireMonkey, a Form's [`Handle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.Handle) property is of type [`TWindowHandle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TWindowHandle) (a class defined in the [FMX.Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types) unit). On Windows, it is implemented as [`TWinWindowHandle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.TWinWindowHandle) (a subclass of `TWindowHandle` defined in the [FMX.Platform.Win](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win) unit).

`TWinWindowHandle` stores the `HWND` handle in its [`Wnd`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.TWinWindowHandle.Wnd) property.

To get the actual `HWND` handle, you would need to use [`FmxHandleToHWND()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FmxHandleToHWND):

```
ShellExecute(FmxHandleToHWND(Handle), 'open', PChar(filename), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

This casts the `TWindowHandle` to `TWinWindowHandle` (using [`WindowHandleToPlatform`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Platform.Win.WindowHandleToPlatform)) and then returns its `Wnd` property value.

**Updated** (based on Remy's comments):

Remy points out that the `FmxHandleToHWND` is documented to be deprecated (from [XE4](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FmxHandleToHWND) onwards). This doesn't appear to be backed up by the latest source code, which seems in the case of Delphi 10.1 Berlin RTM version to have dropped the usual `deprecated` modifier, but let's take the documentation's word for it just to be safe.

Instead of `FmxHandleToHWND` you are advised to do exactly what `FmxHandleToHWND` does, which is to call `WindowHandleToPlatform` and access the `Wnd` property, so:

```
ShellExecute(WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle).Wnd, 'open', PChar(filename), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

A better option, though, would be to use [`FormToHWND`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND), which is more a direct replacement for `FmxHandleToHWND` than `WindowHandleToPlatform` (and we can wonder why the docs don't point us at this routine, though the likely answer is the docs writer just got it wrong):

```
ShellExecute(FormToHWND(Handle), 'open', PChar(filename), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: `FmxHandleToHWND()` is deprecated, you are supposed to use `WindowHandleToPlatform()` directly now, eg: `ShellExecute(WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle)->Wnd, 'open', PChar(filename), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Comment: Updated answer to take the documentation's allegation into account

Comment: It is not an allegation, it really is marked as deprecated in the source code, and has been for awhile. Also, an easier way to get the `HWND` of a `TForm` is to use the [`FormToHWND()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND) function in the `FMX.Platform.Win` unit, eg: `ShellExecute(FormToHWND(Self), 'open', PChar(filename), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Comment: The source I looked in was Delphi 10.1 Berlin. No `deprecated` there. Maybe that changed in the Update? Now I look back at Seattle and earlier, I see it there, but not in Berlin RTM. Please check.

Comment: Moreover, if `FormToHWND` is the effective non-deprecated replacement, why does the doc page on `FmxHandleToHWND` refer to coder to `WindowHandleToPlatform`, which is notably not a replacement??

Comment: `FmxHandleToHWND()` has been marked as `deprecated` since XE4 (when `WindowHandleToPlatform()` was first added) and its documentation reflects that. If it is no longer marked in Berlin, I would consider that a bug. As for `FormToHWND()`, that was added in XE5, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

A `TWindowHandle` is a FireMonkey class. A `HWND` is a Windows handle. These are completely different types.

For the VCL, it is fine to pass something like `TForm.Handle`, which is a `HWND`, to `ShellExecute()`. For FireMonkey (FMX), it isn't, since that is a `TWindowHandle`.

Use `GetDesktopWindow()` from unit `Winapi.Windows` instead:

```
ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow, 'open', PChar(filename), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: Don't use the desktop window as a window owner ever. Pass 0 is probably the cleanest.

Comment: @David - Like Jordan (inno-setup) commented on the page you linked, the example Raymond gives is not accurate. I doubt if it was ever accurate. Maybe on 9x.. systems....